# onDrop (javascript) change css

Tags: javascript, css

Can you do an `onDrop` function (JavaScript) and immediately change CSS when element is dropped?

For example an image when you drop it, the width and height of image will change. I'm not really sure how would you do that in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage) library to simplify the implementation.
[Dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage)

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how can you apply that through an image? all i want is to change an image css when you drop it in a div like the size. Cause the setup  is like this,  several small images and one big main image, when you drop this small images to the big image it will  adopt to the size of the big image. So i thought that you just need to manipulate css.